# How to change disabled tag using JQuery multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JQuery to validate a password and confirm_password pair of fields. The problem I facing is that if I include the following function:

```
<script>
    $('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
        if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
            $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
            $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
        } else
            $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    });
</script>
```

Then when the passwords match the submit button becomes enabled. However, if the password is then changed so they don't match the submit button remains enabled.

If I include the following line in the else statement:

```
$("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
```

Then the submit button is always disabled no matter whether the passwords match or not.

Can someone please explain what I am missing and how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your else a block

```
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
        $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
        $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
        $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Without the curly braces only the message is executed by the else and the disabled is always executed.

I would recommend always using curly braces even if you only want to execute a single statement. Makes reading and maintaining code clearer.